# ApEx 19.1 form region item value not passing on insert/create

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I've been designing a new app in ApEx 19.1 and one of the form/reports which I have created will not save a specific column when I click CREATE (SQL Insert action). Debug data shows that the data is in the session state when the CREATE request is being processed. I have verified that the value is not inserted with the other columns by querying the table in SQL Developer.

When I click to edit the item, the page item is blank and the value is not in the session state. I can then choose a value, and it saves correctly (SQL Update action).

I have several other 19.1 form/reports in the app which do not have this problem.

Details:

-ApEx 19.1

-Modal Form page on an Interactive Report

-New Form Region, not legacy DML setup

-DATETIME column type, Date Picker item type
-Required column, Value Required = Yes (and errors occur correctly if left blank)

-The biggest difference between this page and others is that rather than navigating directly from the report page to this form dialog on Create, there is a different modal dialog form that must be filled, and then the user navigates to the form in question.

All of the other fields insert data correctly to their corresponding columns, and I haven't changed any of the Source settings after creation, so I'm not sure what is causing the issue. I've even deleted the pages and rebuilt them with the same results.

Comment: Can you demonstrate your question on apex.oracle.com?

Comment: So the source settings for a field that works matches the source settings to the field that doesn't? (barring the field name, of course)

Comment: @Scott: that is correct. I'll see if I can get a public version throwing the same error per mohamed's comment.

Comment: Just my luck: the version I created in an apex.oracle.com app works perfectly, with no error. I'll continue to compare the differences between the workspaces, but I'll gladly take any insights from folks in the meantime.

Comment: Maybe try mockup the same example again in your own workspace, maybe you've just acciddentally/forgot that you tweaked something.

Comment: I brought the functioning app into my actual workspace and saw the same issue occur, which led me to the answer below. Big facepalm moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue had nothing to do with ApEx, and everything to do with poor DB & app design.

There was an insert trigger on the table which inserted a value to the column in question from an application item which had not been set.

I'll definitely clear that up to avoid future confusion.